# Let $f:[a,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x) = \infty$, show that $f$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am stuck on this question from a problem set. The question itself has two parts so I post them under the same topic (they're pretty much related to each other too - at least in the book). I hope it's ok.

Q1: Let $f:[a,\infty] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ derivative function. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x) = \infty$. Show that $f$ **is not** uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty]$

Attempts:

- I tried to show that if $f'(x)$ isn't blocked, the function cannot be uniformly continuous, but it only works in the opposite direction.
- Showing that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist doesn't help me either.

Q2: Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous function. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} f(x) = L$. Show that $f$ has either minimum or maximum in $\mathbb R$

Attempts:

- Exists $M_1$ (for $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$) and $M_2$ (for $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} f(x)$) and if function gets max or min in $[M_1, M_2]$ which is equal to L, then we're done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**.Fix $\epsilon,\delta>0$.

Since lim$_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=\infty,\exists N$ such that $f'(x)>\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$, if $x>N$.

Then, by MVT, we have that$\;\;\;\forall x>N\;\;\;\exists c\in(x,x+\delta)$ such that $f(x+\delta)-f(x)=f'(c)\delta>\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ were arbitrary, this shows f can not be uniformly continuous.

**2**.Suppose f is not constant. Then $\exists x_0$ such that, say, $f(x_0)>L$.

Since $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=L, \exists N$ such that $f(x_0)>f(x)$ if $|x|>N$.

Now since $f$ is continuous it obtains a maximum on $[-N,N]$, say $f(x_1)$.

Clearly, $f(x_1)\geq f(x_0)$. It follows that $f(x_1)\geq f(x) \;\;\;\forall x\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

A function is uniformly continuous if for every small "range error" $\Delta y$, there is some small \emph{non-zero} "domain error" $\Delta x$ such that a change of $\pm \Delta x$ around \emph{any} element $x$ in the domain will result in a change of only $\pm \Delta y$ in the range.

Now the derivative $dy/dx$ is the ratio between "change in range" and "change in domain". Going back to the definition of uniform continuity, we fixed $\Delta y$ and wanted $\Delta x$ to be bounded \emph{from below} (think why we want a bound from below rather than from above). So the derivative needs to be bounded from above.

---

For the second question, suppose that the function is not constant. Take some point which has a value different from $L$, say $M > L$. Now $M$ is not necessarily the maximum, but perhaps there is a way to identify the maximum, as some kind of supremum?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Try proving by contradiction.  If $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists some $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le 1$ whenever $|x-y| \le \delta$.  Now find an interval $[a,b]$ of length longer than $\delta$ such that $f' > 1/\delta$ on $[a,b]$.  If we pick $x=a$, $y=a+\delta$, what does the mean value theorem tell you about $|f(x)-f(y)|$?

Q2: If $f$ is identically equal to $L$ we are done.  Otherwise there exists $x_0$ with, say, $f(x_0) > L$.  Now find a closed interval $[a,b]$ with $f(x) < f(x_0)$ outside $[a,b]$, and consider the maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$...

Comment: Regarding Q1: How exactly I find the interval [a,b]? and if I understand correctly, then $|f(x) - f(y)| > 1$.

Comment: @Ma.H: Actually, the interval can be of the form $[a,\infty)$.  Use the fact that $f'(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$...